# How to change layout of fragment without recreating it?

Tags: android, layout, fragment, screen, orientation

I have an `Activity` which listens to orientation changed to prevent it from recreating when we rotate screen.

I have some `Fragment` attached to this `Activity`.

When screen orientation is changed, my `Activity` is **not recreated**, and of course my `Fragment` is not recreated. But I want to change its layout.

How can I change layout of `Fragment`without recreating it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use resources modifiers for each layout. For example layouts that should be used in landscape only should go to `res/layout-land` folder

**Edit 1**
Try this

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    void someMyVoid() {
         getFragmentManager()
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.layout, new MyFragment)
                 .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried. But it does not help. Because the `onCreateView` method is not called for re-inflating new layout

Comment: It should be called. Because fragments resides in activities and when activity is recreated fragments recreated to. Supply us with some code

Comment: See my updated answer. My `activity` is not recreated, because it listens to configChange